# Loop through sheets and execute calculations based on dynamic sheet references

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic, reference

Is it possible to loop through a list of sheets and execute some calculations that have sheet references from a different list of worksheets? For example, you have a list (list 1) of your worksheets, which will be the destinations of the calculations, and you have a second list (list 2) of worksheets that the calculations are based on. So, lets say there are sheet1 and sheet2 in list 1, and sheetA and sheetB in list 2. The calculations based on sheetA would appear in sheet1, and calculations based on sheetB would appear in sheet2. I thought the code would look something like this:

```
Sub LoopthroughWorksheets()
Dim sheet_name As Range
Dim sheet_name2 As Range
Set sheet_name2 = Sheets("WS").Range("F:F")
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("C:C")
    If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
                .Range("K1") = .Range("sheet_name2.Value!A14").Value
        End With
    End If
    Next sheet_name
End Sub
```

I'm getting a "Run-time error '1004: Application-defined or object defined error" at this line: `.Range("K1") = .Range("sheet_name2.Value!A14").Value`

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but your code is wrong.

You will have to iterate somehow over both columns C and F, and then retrieve the matching sheet names:

```
Sub LoopthroughWorksheets()
    Dim sheet_name As Range
    Dim sheet_name2 As Range
    Set sheet_name2 = Sheets("WS").Range("F:F")
    ' NEW
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 1

    For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS").Range("C:C")
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
                .Range("K1").Value = Sheets(sheet_name2(counter, 1).Value).Range("A14").Value
                ' NEW                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   
                counter = counter + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next sheet_name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MP24. With this code: `.Range("K1") = Sheets("sheet_name2").Range("A14").Value` I get a run time error 9: subscript out of range. With this code: `.Range("K1") = Sheets(sheet_name2).Range("A14").Value` I get a run time error 13: type mismatch. With this code: `.Range("K1") = Sheets(sheet_name2.Value).Range("A14").Value` I get a run time error 13: type mismatch.

Comment: Any thoughts as to what could still be going wrong? The worksheet list for list one is A1:A51 and for list 2 is F1:F51. Cell A14 contains a number and not text.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much. This will cut down the time I spend coding. I thought this would be a fairly common question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Just curious, how does the counter work? I'm not sure how sheet_name2(1,1) equates to the worksheet listed in cell A1.

Comment: Best is to analyze to code from inside out: `sheet_name2` is a range with all your sheet names (column F). The braces `(counter, 1)` will act as row-column access, i.e. if `counter = 3`, `sheet_name2(3, 1)` will be the third row/first column cell in column F. Then, the construction accesses the value (i.e. cell contents) of this third row/first column, which is your sheet name. Then, it retrieves the sheet using `Sheets(...)` and accesses range A1 on this sheet.